# How are Chrome's "timing" values determined when the HTTP status is "200 from cache"?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, timing

When I see the response status "200 from cache", what's the meaning of the values in the "Timing" tab in Chrome?

As we all know, when the status is "200 from cache", the browser does not send any request.

What's the meaning of "content download" in this context? What about "waiting"? The values change every time I refresh the page.

[image: timing image]